# How do I exlude files with a certain extension from a directory file list?"

Tags: java, arraylist

I am creating a list of files under one Dir recursively. I have one variable( UNPACK_EXT ) defined asa constant and imported to exclude from the search / filelist.

the goal is to return a file list of all files that contain the (STATS_FILE ) variable with out searching any dir that contain ( UNPACK_EXT )
this is part of the code:

I pass in a variable called baseDir,  this is the starting point of my search. I only want to list file that match (STATS_FILE ), however due to the size of directories that contain (UNPACK_EXT ) in the dir name I need to exclude these, as they are already available in other part's of application.

```
Spublic class FindStatFilesTag extends BaseTag
```

{
private String baseDir;

```
@Override
public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException
{
    if ((!isEmpty(var)) && (!isEmpty(baseDir)))
    {
        if (baseDir.contains("TS"))
        {
        String pmr = baseDir;
        JspContext context = getJspContext();
        baseDir = BASE_SF_PATH + "TS" + pmr.charAt(2) + pmr.charAt(3) + pmr.charAt(4) + "/" + pmr.charAt(5) + pmr.charAt(6) + pmr.charAt(7) + "/" + baseDir;

        List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        String startDir = baseDir;

        
            String dirName = startDir + "/" ;
            File dir = new File(dirName);
            fileList.addAll(listAll(dir));
        

        Map<String, List<FileInfo>> fileInfoMap = new TreeMap<String, List<FileInfo>>();

        for (Iterator<File> iter = fileList.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
        {
            File file = iter.next();
            String name = file.getAbsolutePath();

           String shortName = "";
            if ((name.contains(STATS_FILE)) && (!name.contains(UNPACK_EXT)))
            {
                

                shortName = name.substring(name.indexOf(STATS_FILE));
            } 
            
             
        
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(name, "", file.length());

                if (fileInfoMap.containsKey(shortName))
                {
                    List<FileInfo> fileInfoList = fileInfoMap.get(shortName);
                    if (!fileInfoList.contains(fileInfo))
                    {
                        fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
                        Collections.sort(fileInfoList);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    List<FileInfo> fileInfoList = new ArrayList<FileInfo>();
                    fileInfoList.add(fileInfo);
                    fileInfoMap.put(shortName, fileInfoList);
                }
        }
     context.setAttribute(var, fileInfoMap);
     }
```

Comment: Please include your desired behavior.

Comment: The example does not have the UNPACK_EXT variable. We need more source code. Please give a more complete example.

Comment: added additional code

Comment: Hi Jeff, and welcome to Stackoverflow. In order to get helpful answers, you should make it easy for the crowd to help you. So your post title should most likely be a question like "How do I exlude files with a certain extension from a directory file list?". To make it even easier for people to help you out, you should provide a minimal but at least compiling code sample. You should explain that sample a bit and use it to clarify your question.